# Popup dimensions on screen

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I thought I understood the WPF content scaling system but ran into an issue that's mysterious to me.  I have a very simple popup that is supposed to be used as a loupe that opens on top of an image when the user clicks the image.  The XAML is this:

```
    <Popup Name="LoupePopup" AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="False" StaysOpen="True">
        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Azure" />
    </Popup>
```

In code behind, I then tie the popup's placement to an image that is already showing when the popup is opened.  I set the loupe size to half the size of the image with this code:

```
    LoupePopup.PlacementTarget = FullImg;
    LoupePopup.Placement = PlacementMode.Relative;
    LoupePopup.Width = FullImg.ActualWidth / 2;
    LoupePopup.Height = FullImg.ActualHeight / 2;
```

Further code then moves the loupe along with MouseMove, but that does not really relate to the issue here: I'd expect the loupe to be exactly half the width/height of the image, but it is not - it is quite a bit larger (by about 18%).  I verified the actual image size and the actual size of the window on which it is displayed, as well as the mouse coordinates. Those dimensions/point coordinates all made perfect sense, but why would the popup not use the same width/height scaling as the other elements here?

For clarification: The image covers 80% or so of the screen, so this is not just an issue of a few pixels.  The window is a child window created in code, and the popup is defined in the XAML of the main window, but both windows are set to full screen size.

Appreciate your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying more options I had to realize that the child-versus main window aspect caused the issue. The image was showing in a child window; the popup was defined in the main window.  After moving the popup XAML to the child window, the popup dimensions were correct.

Not sure I understand why (both windows have the full screen dimensions and *should* use the same scaling, but at least this solves my issue.  Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is so because border thickness is not taking into account when calculating LoupePopup size
or default margin and padding of popup or image

Comment: BorderThickness is 2 while the delta in expected vs. actual width is >100 units, so that won't explain it.  Image and popup both have neither margins nor padding definitions, so those should all be zero.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you should have a look at the `Stretch` property of the image. If you have a width and a height defined on the image the ActualWidth/-Height are influenced by the Stretch property. Setting it to Fill makes the ActualWidth/-Height equal to the defined Width and Height.

Comment: Appreciate your thought.  However, the issue I'm seeing is not with the image - it displays exactly as I want it to and its ActualWidth and ActualHeight are exactly what you'd expect them to be.  The image Width and Height properties are actually not defined - its size is set by the size of a Grid cell.

Comment: @Lon: Then I don't know. What does the `LoupePopup.ActualWidth` and `LoupePopup.ActualHeight` tell compared to `LoupePopup.Width/-Height`

Comment: Width and Height are settings you use in code that tell the WPF engine what sizes you would like to have IF that is possible.  ActualWidth and ActualHeight are what the WPF engine reports back once rendering has completed.  They could be the same, but then, they can also be different.  In any case, only the Actual... values really tell you the dimensions of the UIElement being displayed.

Comment: @Lon: Yes, I know that, but I what on your LoupePopup? Are they as expected? :-)

Comment: As I said in my original post: they were exactly what I expected.